# MethodAccessException when updating a record in sqlite db

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-7

I encounter this exception when I try to updating a record with following statement.

```
UPDATE GroupTable SET groupId=100 WHERE groupId=101
```

I tested the statement under SQLite Manager of Firefox plug-in, and it works.
The error message is as following image. It crashed at the `os_win_c.cs`, the method named `getTempname()`.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I modified the original codes and fixed this bug.

The `Path.GetTempPath()` doesn't work because the sandbox enviroment. It has no access right.
I fixed by following codes. And it works now.

```
static int getTempname(int nBuf, StringBuilder zBuf)
{
      const string zChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
      StringBuilder zRandom = new StringBuilder(20);
      i64 iRandom = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
      {
        sqlite3_randomness(1, ref iRandom);
        zRandom.Append((char)zChars[(int)(iRandom % (zChars.Length - 1))]);
      }

      //! Modified by Toro, 2011,05,10
      string tmpDir = "tmpDir";
      IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
      store.CreateDirectory(tmpDir);
      //zBuf.Append(Path.GetTempPath() + SQLITE_TEMP_FILE_PREFIX + zRandom.ToString());
      zBuf.Append(tmpDir + "/" + SQLITE_TEMP_FILE_PREFIX + zRandom.ToString());

      return SQLITE_OK;
}
```

The above patch will result in an extra folder `tmpDir` in the isolatedstorage, and the temp files won't be deleted automatically, so it needs to be delete by self. I tried to delete those files in `tmpDir` in the method of `winClose` inside `os_win_c.cs`, and I found it will result in crash when I do `VACUUM`. Finally, I delete those tmp files when I closed the database. The following is a Dispose method in `SQLiteConnection` class.

```
public void Dispose()
{
    if (_open)
    {
         // Original codes for close sqlite database
         Sqlite3.sqlite3_close(_db);
         _db = null;
         _open = false;

         // Clear tmp files in tmpDir, added by Toro 2011,05,13
        IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        string tmpDir = "tmpDir";
        if (store.DirectoryExists(tmpDir) == false) return;

        string searchPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(tmpDir, "*.*");
        foreach (string file in store.GetFileNames(searchPath)) {
            store.DeleteFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(tmpDir, file));
        }
    }
}
```